# Oracle Not Like

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your assistance with the below query as I am not sure how to modify to show me the correct results.
Column2 has records that begin with:

```
005....
04....
01....
05....
XYZ....
234....
6789....
V875....
```

I would like to modify the query to exclude records that begin with a single zero for example 04,01,05 (from the example above), the rest are okay. I tried NOT LIKE ‘0%’ but it excludes records starting with zero. How can I do this? Below is a query sample I have.

```
Select * from table1
where column 1 in (‘A’,’B’,’C’) and column2 ????
```

Comment: Let's clarify: `04`, `01` are not desired; `0X` should be included. Correct? The last sentence is not clear.

Comment: Hi - good question, anything that begins with a single zero (0x) should not be included. Many Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to exclude records that begin with a single zero:

```
WHERE NOT Regexp_like( column, '^0[^0]' );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using just `like`:

```
where col not like '0%' or col like '00%'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey just an alternative if you are reluctant to use REGEXP here. We
>   can use some OLD school methods to do this. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT B.NMM
FROM
  (SELECT a.nmm,
    CASE
      WHEN SUBSTR(a.nmm,1,1) = '0'
      THEN NULLIF(SUBSTR(a.nmm,1,1), SUBSTR(a.nmm,2,1))
      ELSE NULL
    END chk
  FROM
    (SELECT '005' NMM FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '04' NMM FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '01' NMM FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '05' NMM FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'XYZ' NMM FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '234' NMM FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'V875' NMM FROM DUAL
    )A
  )b
WHERE B.chk IS NULL;

-----------------------------------OUTPUT-----------------------------------

NMM
005
XYZ
234
V875
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way

```
Where substr(colmn, 1,1)='0'
```

But this approciate deny use of insex on column. If this is not a problem, should work good